# Android MuPDF Error

Tags: android, android-layout, java, mupdf

Im adding MUPDF to android app doing :

(1)  http://mupdf.blogspot.com/

(2)  http://pastebin.com/YzHUhzE7

when i try to do :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ChoosePDFActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I get this :

```
07-19 05:22:37.255: W/dalvikvm(16084): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/artifex/mupdfdemo/MuPDFCore;
    07-19 05:22:37.255: D/AndroidRuntime(16084): Shutting down VM
    07-19 05:22:37.255: W/dalvikvm(16084): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.openFile(MuPDFActivity.java:212)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.onCreate(MuPDFActivity.java:311)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mupdf from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.example.addingmupdf-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.example.addingmupdf-2]: findLibrary returned null
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.<clinit>(MuPDFCore.java:13)
    07-19 05:22:37.275: E/AndroidRuntime(16084):    ... 16
```

Does anyone know what wrong here? 
I'm open to any other sugg. to import mupdf to existing android project.

Comment: Did you compiled the C (jni) libs? Have a look here: http://www.mupdf.com/doc/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have finally wrote entire process [here](http://dixitpatel.com/integrating-pdf-in-android-application/) to integrate pdf into android application.

Comment: @A_J What you mean? you cant click it? I just up dated the link.

Comment: Hi, i followed all the steps you described:
http://dixitpatel.com/integrating-pdf-in-android-application/
But i get the same error you complained about on the first message, how did you fixed it ?

Comment: What do you mean in step 5 of your tutorial "than command: ‘make' "

Comment: Link is dead, Paste code instead of links *they became invalid over a time*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to run the app in the emulator,check the CPU/EBI o match the architecture used in Application.mk